# How to get the best resolution of image from image @srcset attribute using Xidel?

Tags: bash, srcset, xidel

I have this code to list the sizes of images from the @srcset attribute:

```
cat <<EOF | xidel -s - -e 'extract(//@srcset,"(\d+w)",1,"*")'
<img ... srcset="https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-696x457.jpg 696w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-220x144.jpg 220w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-300x197.jpg 300w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-768x504.jpg 768w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-475x312.jpg 475w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu.jpg 800w, 
https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-741x486.jpg 741w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-640x420.jpg 640w" />
EOF

696w
220w
300w
768w
475w
800w
741w
640w
```

How to get the best resolution using Xidel? In this case, only `800w`?
The largest size can be in the beginning, the end or the middle (random order).

Xidel Output expected:

```
cat <<EOF | xidel -s - -e '?'
<img ... srcset="https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-696x457.jpg 696w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-220x144.jpg 220w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-300x197.jpg 300w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-768x504.jpg 768w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-475x312.jpg 475w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu.jpg 800w, 
https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-741x486.jpg 741w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-640x420.jpg 640w" />
EOF

800w
```

or output the full URL:

```
cat <<EOF | xidel -s - -e '?'
<img ... srcset="https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-696x457.jpg 696w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-220x144.jpg 220w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-300x197.jpg 300w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-768x504.jpg 768w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-475x312.jpg 475w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu.jpg 800w, 
https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-741x486.jpg 741w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-640x420.jpg 640w" />
EOF

https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the largest width, simply put `max()` around it: `-e 'max(extract(//@srcset,"(\d+w)",1,"*"))'`.

To extract the url with the largest width you'd first have to split each url:

```
$ cat <<EOF | xidel -s - -e 'tokenize(//@srcset,", ")'
<img srcset="https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-696x457.jpg 696w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-220x144.jpg 220w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-300x197.jpg 300w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-768x504.jpg 768w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-475x312.jpg 475w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-741x486.jpg 741w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-640x420.jpg 640w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu.jpg 800w" />
EOF

https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-696x457.jpg 696w
https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-220x144.jpg 220w
https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-300x197.jpg 300w
https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-768x504.jpg 768w
https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-475x312.jpg 475w
https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-741x486.jpg 741w
https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-640x420.jpg 640w
https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu.jpg 800w
```

Then, to even my own surprise, you can again wrap `max()` around it:

```
$ cat <<EOF | xidel -s - -e 'max(tokenize(//@srcset,", "))'
<img srcset="https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-696x457.jpg 696w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-220x144.jpg 220w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-300x197.jpg 300w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-768x504.jpg 768w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-475x312.jpg 475w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-741x486.jpg 741w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-640x420.jpg 640w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu.jpg 800w" />
EOF

https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu.jpg 800w
```

To return only the url you could do: `-e 'substring-before(max(tokenize(//@srcset,", "))," ")'`.